# How would I make my bot made in discord.py create a text message with custom permissions?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have a discord bot made with python3.6, and I want him to create a text channel, but only for admins.

I know how to create a text channel using `await client.create_channel()`, but I do not know how would I set custom permissions and how would I send a message to it.

Thank you!

My code (in case you need it):

```
@client.event
async def discord.on_server_join(server):
    await client.send_message(channel, "Thank you for using Phantom. From all the developers, we want to thank you, as we know there are thousands of other bots out there.")
    await client.send_message(channel, "You should see that a new channel was created and is called \"Phantom\". That is the phantom moderation channel and is used for administrating your phantom instance.")
    server = ctx.message.server
    await client.create_channel(server, "Phantom", type=discord.ChannelType.text)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
# The code continues here, but I think you only need the on_server_join function.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`create_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_channel) provides a similar example.  Below, it is updated to make the channel visible to any role with administrator permissions.

```
def overwrites(server):
    invisible = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
    visible = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    perms = [(server.default_role, invisible)]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role.permissions.administrator:
            perms.append((role, visible))
    return perms

@client.event
async def discord.on_server_join(server):
    await client.send_message(channel, "Thank you for using Phantom. From all the developers, we want to thank you, as we know there are thousands of other bots out there.")
    await client.send_message(channel, "You should see that a new channel was created and is called \"Phantom\". That is the phantom moderation channel and is used for administrating your phantom instance.")
    server = ctx.message.server
    channel = await client.create_channel(server, "Phantom", *overwrites(server), type=discord.ChannelType.text)
    await client.send_message(channel, "Hello!")
```

Comment: I know this might sound stupid, but, once created the channel, how would I send a message through it? Using `await client.send_message("Phantom", "hello")`?

Comment: @TehAlex11 See my edit.  You can capture the return value of `create_channel` and use that as the target for `send_message`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is trying to check the if a player has a specific role,
for instance, checking if the player has the admin role. Here's a example.

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('/admin'):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles,id='420576440111726592') #Replace the numbers with your role's id
    if "340682622932090890" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]: #Do the same here
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Aye you have admin!")
    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "You do not have permissions to do this command")
```

I'm not a expert and also haven't tested this out, So tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: This also helped me a lot, but the only problem is that I want my bot to run in every server, so I also need to see what's the Admin role ID.

Comment: Then instead of checking for the role you should check for the permissions. Instead of `if 340682622932090890" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:`
do `if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:`